# VB Round function changing decimal separator

Tags: vba, rounding

I provide a spreadsheet to users around the world and must then, of course, adapt it to the various regional formats. I create the spreadsheet in the US, using those regional settings. A user in Russia mentioned a problem in which textboxes in a dialog box weren't displaying the correct decimal separator (showing a period instead of a comma). This is the code I created to attempt correct the problem:

```
Sub Decimals()
    Dim ws_Test As Worksheet
    
    Set ws_Test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

    On Error GoTo errhandling
        stDec_Sep = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)
        If stDec_Sep = "." Then
            uf_Decimal.tbDecimal = Round(ws_Test.Range("Decimal_Value"), 3)
            uf_Decimal.Show
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If stDec_Sep = "," Then
            uf_Decimal.tbDecimal.Value = Round(Val(GetNumber_Comma(ws_Test.Range("Decimal_Value"))), 3)
            uf_Decimal.Show
            Exit Sub
        End If
    errhandling:
        MsgBox "Operation failed."
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

What we found is that the Round function was converting the numbers back to a period for the decimal point. Switching the conversion from decimal point to comma happen after the Round function fixed the problem.

```
uf_Decimal.tbDecimal.Value = GetNumber_Comma(Round(Val(ws_Test.Range("Decimal_Value"), 3)))
```

I find no mention of this quirk with the Round function anywhere. Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before?

Comment: vba is en-us centric.  when dealing with text that needs to be converted to numbers then back to text.  the text must be in en-us format all the way till the end, then one can format the number back to text and input it into the textbox.

Comment: The weird part is that when I changed my regional settings to use a comma for the decimal, a space for the thousands (same as Russian), the original code worked fine. It reads a number from a cell into a textbox, rounding it on the way, allows the user to change it, and puts the new number back into the cell. Didn't work on the Russian computer though, not until we made the change to that line.